# DICOM HTML5 vs JAVA viewer

Tags: java, html, comparison, benchmarking, dicom

I'm going to create a DICOM viewer based on HTML5 and available for DICOM JS libraries.
I've already had an experience in creating similar application in Java,using DCM4che library.

My task at the University is to provide a profound technical analysis of these two applications - web and Java. 
I don't know what criteria I should take into consideration.

I was thinking about loading a whole series of images and measure the time (the most simple benchmarking).
Later, I can laso compare these two technologies in general.

Can you give me any clues?
What factors are crucial for both Web and Java applications connected with DICOM viewer?

I'm not specialist in the field of benchmarking, especially related to DICOM files and image display.

Answer (score 3):

Benchmarking is probably not applicable here, as it implies comparing your product to the industry's top product(s). But you definitely will need to collect performance metrics to understand the differences and implications of the chosen technologies.

Which metrics to take is up to you, but they will have to be in a context of showing to the potential user, which is a better solution. Typical metrics include: time from request to viewing the first image; if you support handing protocols, the next one would be seeing all the relevant images. You will need to compare with multiple modalities and multiple studies.

Next metrics would be how fast can a diagnostician reach the middle of a larger stack by moving through the slide deck and identifying relevant area of interest (i.e. images in the series have to render fully). This is harder to measure, but really gives you an idea of the future speed with which diagnoses can be made. I would approach it as follows.

For starters, I would automate both solutions to load up a good 120 images series of 512x512px 16bit depth CT, run through them displaying each slide start to finish, then close the series, and measure the time. This test can be expanded to also apply window and LUT to each image.

A series of images, e.g. for CT, can easily go into gigabytes of data. Both, Java and HTML5 might run out of memory. Do you handle local caching? Streaming? Come up with some metrics around it too. But most of all, performance measurement requires careful planning and thought exercise. When I read metrics, I always look for relevance to the potential users and for potential holes in the logic of the one who was measuring. Did she or he try to cut corners by simplifying real life too much?